# curl_easy_perform return CURLE_OK ,but the write callback func return data 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: libcurl, gateway

I use curl_easy_perform and set the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and  `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`.

Sometimes it returns `CURLE_OK`, but the write callback function returns data "502 Bad Gateway".

Why would it error but return `CURLE_OK` and how can I resolve this error.

Comment: Could we see an example of the instructions you are using?

Comment: the code block like   Init ,curl_easy_setopt(m_curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &WriteData);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &m_sWriteBuf);
DoPerform          
 curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_URL, m_sUrl.c_str());
 curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, m_sFields.c_str());
curl_easy_perform(m_curl);                                                                                             CallBack Func
WriteData(void* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)                      {  char* pSrc = (char* )buf;
  std::string* pDst = (std::string* )userp; }

Answer (score 0):

libcurl will not return an error for HTTP transfers that worked fine. The actual transferring of HTTP.

To extract the HTTP response code from a HTTP response like yours, use [curl_easy_getinfo](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html)(... [CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE.html) ) after the completed transfer.